# Split comma-separated input box values and then store in database

Tags: php, sql

I have a text input box where you can type tags seperated by commas. I want to store these tags separately in a table but I have no idea how to do that. 
I know I have to seperate the tags after they are posted so I now have this

```
$array = explode(',', $_POST['tag']);
```

Is this a good start and how do I have to go on after that?

Comment: Search in google for inserting data in sql with php..

Comment: I know how to do that but I don't know how to store separated values.

Comment: you need to loop through the `$array` and insert each values

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Creating array from your input field as in your code

`$array = explode(',', $_POST['tag']);`

Create a mysql multi insert query using foreach loop
simillar to this:

```
    $id=mysqli_insert_id($con);//get your project id here
    $sql="";    
    foreach($array as $tag_name){
       //modify below to add $id along with $tag_name
       $sql.="('{$id}','{$tag_name}'),"; // you need to remove last comma else it will throw mysql error  
    }

    if($sql!=""){
    //rtrim to remove last ',' from string. 
    $sql=rtrim($sql,',');

    $sql="INSERT INTO tags_tbl (project_id,tag) VALUES {$sql};"`
```

}

now use `mysqli_query($con,$sql)` to insert values in database

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I now have this code:

  $id = mysqli_insert_id($con);

        foreach($array as $tag_name){
            $sql.="('{$tag_name}')";
        }
        if($sql!="")
            $sql="INSERT INTO tags (project_id, tag) VALUES ('$id','$sql')";

            $query2 = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
    }

Nothing gets inserted into the tags table. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: let me change my answer to add project_id